# Can I have someone other than my father as the wali?

Tags: nikah, wali

I am a 25 year old woman. I was engaged 3 years ago with my parents' consent although it is a love marriage. At that time both my parents were reluctant, still we convinced them to get their blessing. A year later, i discovered that my father had been taking money from his sister and nephews and had promised them me and my sister's hand in marriage, and this was the reason that he mistreated my in-laws and also did not agree to the relation. This act of my father has disgusted me and he has even confronted it in front of the whole family that he took monthly money and in return promised and encouraged my cousins to contact us sisters and try to be over friendly.

I feel as if my father is pimping us out.
Ever since all the truth has been revealed my father has insulted my fiance in public and has also beaten me when I raised my voice. On top of it, me and my fiance tried to visit a few pious mawlana sahibs and spiritual people, and each one of them has told us the same thing that my father is doing some sort of black magic with the aid of his sister to destroy my life. I have observed with my own eyes and seen my father burning paper and mix it in my drink and food.

Now I am set to marry in a few months, I don't want my pimp of a father to be my wali because I know he will insult my in-laws and I am also afraid that he will do something to harm my future life.
My brothers are young and not of age.  Can I appoint any reasonable and pious person outside of family to be my wali at nikah?

Comment: Before I answer your question, what do you mean by your brother is "not of age"? Is he not mature enough? Or has he not hit puberty yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you can only dispose of your father if he refuses the marriage. But if he shows up and accepts the marriage while insulting your in-laws, he is still accepting the marriage, so he is not considered an obstacle.

Comment: Allah said the believers are walis (awliya) of each other.  If your family isn't capable than any believer can be there, if needed.  There's no evidence that a family member must be the one to do it.

Comment: @Zainab, as related info. :

[Islamic Marriage](http://www.al-islam.org/islamic-marriage-syed-athar-husain-sh-rizvi)
 .   /   .

[Duty of Husbands and Wives](http://www.al-islam.org/principles-marriage-family-ethics-ayatullah-ibrahim-amini)
 .   /   .

[Qur’an and Mut’ah](http://www.al-islam.org/nikah-al-mutah-zina-or-sunnah-toyib-olawuyi/1-mutah-quran)

Comment: The answer to your question might lie here:
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40777/can-a-girl-marry-on-her-own

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a legal verdict on a multifaceted, real-life situation. The answer would depend on the school of thought, would require more investigation into the matter, and would require verification of the claims made here etc. This is the job of a Qadi \ Mufti or an Islamic court.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a fatwa site.